# How does struct work in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct point
{int X, Y;} a[4], b[4];
```

I found this piece of code on some program that works and I don't understand how this works and I can't find anything about how it works?

Can anyone explain it please?

Comment: That piece of code is not valid C++ as there are no `Struct` and `Int` keywords in C++.

Comment: I would suggest one of these to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Is the choice of upper/lower chars in the code sample an accident? As @Ron pointed out correctly: `Struct point { Int X, Y; } a[4], b[4];` (as is) is not correct code. `struct point { int X, Y; } a[4], b[4];` would be. The latter defines a `struct`, named `point` with two components (`X` and `Y`) of type `int` and declares two instances (`a` and `b`) of the just defined `struct point` which are both arrays with 4 elements.

Comment: @Scheff -- yes, it's an accident. Some devices are too smart to be useful; they insist that when you type `struct` at the beginning of a line you meant to type `Struct`.

Comment: After you edited your question, it turns out that the answer of Some Programmer Dude is correct. So, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it to "pay" for his effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the same as

```
struct point
{
    int X, Y;
};

point a[4];
point b[4];
```

In other words, you define a structure (named `point`) and then declare two variables `a` and `b`, both being arrays of four elements of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is array of structure which can store 4 element of structure type for exampme x[0].a=10 and x[0].b=20....till x[3].